# Virtual hosts file not redirecting to correct directory

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework2, virtualhost, virtual-hosts

I'm trying to set my virtual host to point to a directory when //zf2-tutorial.localhost/ is entered in the address bar:

My `/etc/apache2/sites-available/zf2-tutorial.localhost` file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
         ServerName zf2-tutorial.localhost
         DocumentRoot /var/www/zf2-tutorial/public
         SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
         <Directory /var/www/zf2-tutorial/public>
                 DirectoryIndex index.php
                 AllowOverride All 
                 Order allow,deny
                 Allow from all
         </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My `/etc/hosts file`

```
127.0.0.1       zf2-tutorial.localhost localhost
127.0.1.1       martyn-Lenovo-B590

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

..but doesn't work. Only shows the root directory files (/var/www as when I enter just //localhost/).

When I go to //localhost/zf2-tutorial/public/ I can see my site, I want this to be the root of //zf2-tutorial.localhost/ though.

Any suggestions?

Comment: has apache config been reloaded after changing?

Comment: Yes. I get this issue though on restart - `AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message`. I don't think it's related to this issue though as the IP address in question is 127.0.0.1. Anyway yes I've restarted.

Comment: Well, fix that anyway and try again.

Comment: Fixed. Problem remains.

Comment: is there a NameVirtualHost directive anywhere in your configuration? including in the distribution provided config files.

Comment: Not that I'm aware, I've certainly not added anything like that myself. The configuration directories in my /etc/apache/ are `apache2.conf  conf-available  conf-enabled  envvars  magic  mods-available  mods-enabled  ports.conf  sites-available  sites-enabled`. Btw I'm running on Ubuntu if that helps.

Comment: try adding NameVirtualHost *  to your main configuration. Reason: "With the NameVirtualHost directive you specify the IP address on which the server will receive requests for the name-based virtual hosts."

Comment: Maybe I done something wrong, I added `NameVirtualHost *` to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` but get the following message: `AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:225` on restart

Comment: dunno. according http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost, it's Available in Apache HTTP Server 2.2.21 and later

Comment: No problems, I'll keep at it. Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: btw, i'm running apache 2.2.22 which doesn't complain while having NameVirtualHost * in its configuration

Comment: I'm running Apache/2.4.9

Comment: Those files are run in alphabetical order. I guess yours is the latest one. Does the `sites-enabled`-directory contains a file with the line `ServerAlias *.localhost`? That will conflict with this one - unless that file get parsed **after** your `zf2-file`.

Comment: Oh, and re-reading your question: did you copy (or better create a symlink) that file to `sites-enabled`. Apache does read `sites-enabled` not `sites-available`.